# Custom Domain Heroku app cannot provide a secure connection: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: ssl, heroku, subdomain

I have a Heroku app and am using a custom subdomain to point to it. Let's say my subdomain is blog.mysite.com.

When I navigate to the site, chrome throws the error: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. In the address bar, it automatically reroutes to https://blog.mysite.com. Is this the issue? Why is it not just http://blog.mysite.com?

My domain is through bluehost if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running a free dyno, you will not get TLS support on your custom subdomain. Upgrade it to at least the "Hobby" tier and it will provision a free certificate to match your custom subdomain.

As for why it automatically reroutes, that's something happening within your application or custom process configuration. Heroku doesn't automatically re-route from http to https.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I'd neglected to set up [Automated Certificate Management](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management) in Heroku. Enabling this fixed the problem.